Problem with Relaunching App After Dismissing vision pro
So I am programming an app that performs image tracking and then displays a view. The problem is that when I dismiss the app and relaunch it, it shows the view instead of restarting the detection process. How can I make the app restart the detection process upon relaunching? how can i add parameters that make sure that the app always start with a specific view first and then get to the second view
here is the all the view and i want to always ondismiss, onrelaunch... always start with the splashView
import SwiftUI
import UIKit

@main
@MainActor
struct demo16App: App {
@State private var model = ImageTrackingModel()
@ObservedObject var viewModel = OptionsViewModel()
@ObservedObject var webSocketService = WebSocketService()
@Environment(\.openWindow) private var openWindow
@UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate

var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
       SplashView()
            
    }.windowStyle(.plain)
    
    ImmersiveSpace(id:"Content"){
        ContentView()
            .environment(model)
            .handlesExternalEvents(preferring: [], allowing: [])
            
    }.windowStyle(.plain)
    
    ImmersiveSpace(id: "ImmersiveSpace") {
        ImmersiveView()
    }.windowStyle(.plain)
    
    WindowGroup(id: "secondWindow") {
        VStack {
            VideoView()
                .zIndex(100)
        }
    }
    WindowGroup(id:"immersiveView"){
        Text("Simple Text View")
    }
    WindowGroup(id: "thirdWindow") {
        VStack {
            SwiftUIView(
                viewModel: OptionsViewModel()
            ).environment(model)
        }
    }.windowStyle(.plain)
}

}

use scenePhase Environment to detect

In SwiftUI use the View structs as the view model, not objects

so their is no function that manipulate the onResume() for the vision Pro?
